# how to use JavascriptExecutor in mocha webdriverio

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, webdriver-io

[image]
[image]
I use mocha, webdriverio selenium-standalone framework. I want to Click element using JavaScriptExecutor，but doesn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

[image]

```
it('click icon',function(){
    browser.waitForVisible(elementselector.dockServiceButton, 2000);
    assert.ok(browser.isExisting(elementselector.dockServiceButton)); 

    dockServiceButtonElement=$('//div[@class="icon-dock icon-dock-service "]')
    JavaScriptExecutor ex = (JavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
    ex.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", dockServiceButtonElement);
}
```

Comment: Hello Dear
If you get resolution of this problem please post the solution
It would help us

I am also unable to use javascript executor in my code . I'm using webdriverio with NodeJs

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, made it work using:

```
// clicks on element using JavaScript
browser.addCommand("jsClick", function(this: ElementResult) {
  this.then((element) => {
    browser.execute("arguments[0].click();", element.value);
  });
});
```

This code is also working

```
browser.addCommand("jsClick", function(this: any) {
  browser.execute("arguments[0].click();", this.element().value);
});
```

More about addCommand:
http://webdriver.io/api/utility/addCommand.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't use javascript executor for this.
You already do proper click in test 'login system', so just use the same:

```
browser.click(dockServiceButtonElement);
// or you can call click method directly on element object:
dockServiceButtonElement.click()
```

Source: http://webdriver.io/api/action/click.html

Comment: ,thank you for your answer,but i can't use "browser.click" in this page，because when i use that meathod it has a error "element is not clickable",

i have analyzed the reason,Neither the page need time to located nor this element is not in main windows,so i want to use other meathod to click, do you known javascript executor can be use ?and how to use it ,thank you

Comment: No, javascript executor can't be used for clicking on dom elements.
If you say that element is visible in main window, maybe different (invisible) element is placed on top of it. 
Try to run ```browser.waitForVisible(`//div[@class="icon-dock icon-dock-service "]`, 5000, true);``` before the click. 
Can you share the page you try to run your test on? Or put it in https://jsfiddle.net/ so I can try by myself? 
I am sure it is very simple fix.

Comment: thank you very much,your reason is correct,i found this button can be clicked now useing browser.click ,but i  have another question, when i Click on customer service button , the customer service window will pop up, but the window type is not Alert popup box.
Not div, not new window, windowhandle can only capture the original window ID, i unable to check the new window page ,do you have any ideas

Comment: i have add two picture ,you can enter image describtion for reference，thank you